# Count record of Excel sheet before upload

Tags: excel, laravel-8, laravel-excel

I am working on Upload excel sheet. I need to count records of the excel sheet before upload to use as condition. I am using [this](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) package. My code is like below.

```
public function import() 

    {
        Excel::import(new UsersImport,request()->file('file'));

        return back();

    }
```

How can I count record before upload ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the package you are using. I use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The source code to count the number of rows of a file (xls, xlsx, csv ...) is below:

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("05featuredemo.xlsx");
$highestRow = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
echo $highestRow;
```

In your case probably:

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load(request()->file('file'));
$highestRow = $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
if ($highestRow < 10) {
    // Error
}
return back();
```